# not getting scope of this is map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is my state**

```
state = {
    socialFeedButtons: {
      "Make Offer": this.props.userData.isNegotiable,
      "Buy Direct": !this.props.userData.isNegotiable,
      "Exchange": this.props.userData.availableForExchange,
      "Chat": false
    }
  }
```

I'm calling the function in my render but scope of this is not working

```
getSocialFeedButtons = () => (
    Object.keys(this.state.socialFeedButtons).map((buttonKey,index) => (
      {this.state.socialFeedButtons} ?
      <div className="col">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-outline-dark w-100"
          style={{
            borderColor: "#76797B !important",
            color: "#202022 !important",
            fontSize: "14px",
          }}
        >
          {buttonKey}
        </button>
      </div>
      : ""
      
    )
  )
```

**got stuck while playing with react
I'm not getting why this scope is not working
**

Comment: I'm not sure what the logic behind the condition `this.state.socialFeedButtons ? ""` as this state always truthy

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax typos, you can use [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBzOMDKEwEsCGANgGJxwAmAQgK4wzQDOABALxMAUAlKwHwcA6UJsKYB5AEYArOGBgA6ANZwAng3YwAFrgZyGMfPF04CJMlVr0oDTnIC2+AA7t24i9ADSKgDS4o5OAAe3Cx87IIiIprauvqGDMZEpBQ0dIxMAPzhEUwAPOS4AG5MYIT4DAwAcvi2cCz84BCE9TxZ2bmuqVCtbUwwyg619R2W9d1tJWWV1YMg4jBCc1AAtBC0hL5wS+T4AE4KTADuSwCMAAyno0I9wnrKhLXAwGM94hA7-jsAwo1vSEz1AGIAOwANiBAE4gZQmABCXC2BxvfSwepeZ7jH47P6AgBMpzxOJxsPhiJ2yJgqPR2QAZtAsLgAF5wbEgY4AFgcAUpV2uAF9eVSWjyesBhh4VALhREcgB6MVQIVtWX5AqK7Isy7CTjakBeEAQBwwXCMZCgXY7CAHAAKuwQDGQICIB3wql1sx2+DASiwDk9vlQyBgO2ocD1cFs4go-nIABl8FBUNR8OhiG97HR-Q78LQIG6NDBbIQAOpaeAMX1gOCYO24I0FWvKB1gcpu3wMOBkq0e1D2ZDUojtvWSBgBSger0YTDTGMbPsD0MgYcBTD++4ARWoEHgc8Ig5Avp27Z2DvE+EjhDdDh2vhgRdw5E0yAAHKc9VeIO2ix6HA6r3AjwUcBugAjpu8Bdga9ooGUSxQGYFBujscCgbgSFdsmvZIP2u4Lu2ti4IGwa4aucAbluQFYfOer6OId4PhoyA4tRHq4OsCbfLYmEgP+ACsbrUO2AAqZ5Qdhe4FCGACSfgIFgYDXoaACCfiYH09w7u2-JAA) to try and fix it.

```
getSocialFeedButtons = () => (
    Object.keys(this.state.socialFeedButtons).map((buttonKey,index) => (
      this.state.socialFeedButtons ?
      <div className="col">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-outline-dark w-100"
          style={{
            borderColor: "#76797B !important",
            color: "#202022 !important",
            fontSize: "14px",
          }}
        >
          {buttonKey}
        </button>
      </div>
      : ""
  )))
```